# Turn JSON script URL into variables in PHP

Tags: php, twitter, json

I was wondering how on earth to get a json string into php.. here's my string:

(go here) http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.onewiththem.com.au/&callback=twttr.receiveCount

and you should see this returned:

```
twttr.receiveCount({"count":0,"url":"http:\/\/www.onewiththem.com.au\/"});
```

I was wondering how to get the count number and have it set up in the variable $count ?

Comment: First of all, remove `&callback=`.  Are you asking for a JSON parser?

Comment: use json_decode() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2):

Simple, using `json_decode()` and `file_get_contents()`:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.onewiththem.com.au/'));
echo $data->count;
```

Note that I removed the `&callback=` from the URL, because that's only used for JSONP and PHP doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean get it in javascript, then the `data` in your callback function is the object. You could get the count just by `data.count`.

```
twttr.reciveCount = function (data) {
  console.log(data.count);
  // do the rest
}
```

If you call the api from php, then you should not use the `callback` parameter. Get the JSON response and then use `json_decode` to decode it. (Don't forget urlencode the url parameter.)

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url='.urlencode('http://www.onewiththem.com.au/'));
$json = json_decode($response);
echo $json->count;
```